# Reaplicando CSS em outra página

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando reaplicar o mesmo CSS de uma tela de login, em um de cadastro que tem 2 inputs a mais. Porém eles não ficam com a mesma configuração e não consigo achar o erro.

o CSS está assim:

```css
.input-field {
  position: relative;
}

form .input-field:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.input-field .underline::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.input-field .underline::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(240, 191, 9, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 154, 38, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 106, 0, 1) 100%);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.input-field input:focus~.underline::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.input-field input {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
    <div class="underline"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Digite seu usuário">
    <div class="underline"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha">
    <div class="underline"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirmar sua senha">
    <div class="underline"></div>
  </div>
```

[image: tela]

Answer (score 0):

Você tem de fazer load do seu CSS no outro ficheiro. No HTML você deve ter algo como `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">` O caminho `assets/css/main.css` você tem de trocar pelo seu caminho e colocar dentro da tag `<head>`. Por simples palavras você precisa de carregar o CSS em todas as paginas que quer partilhar estilos.

Comment: Isso foi feito, porém continua da forma como na imagem.

Comment: abra a console do browser e veja se tem erro de ficheiro faltando

Comment: usei o codigo que você postou e criei um exemplo na sua pergunta, se você conferir não vai ter os estilos aplicados, de certeza que não errou nas class's e id's?

Comment: é que foi basicamente copia e cola, só adicionei mais dois inputs com a mesma class's. Isso que é estranho.

Comment: Então é porque não deve estar a carregar o ficheiro, dá uma conferida na consola do browser e vê se não tem erro de falta de ficheiro. Pode ser que o caminho do ficheiro esteja errado